# Switching Tab Screen from Stack Navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

So, I have the following setup in React Native Navigation.

```
const Tabs = createBottomTabNavigator({
    Home: Home,
    Profile: Profile,
    Chats: Chats
})

const ParentStack = createStackNavigator({
    Tabs: Tabs,
    UserDetails: UserDetails
})
```

The Tabs screen is the initial screen in ParentStack stack navigator & Home is initial screen in Tabs TabNavigator.
I want to navigate to Chats screen from the UserDetails Screen.
I've tried the following code in UserDetails Screen but it didn't work.

```
navigation.navigate("Tabs", { screen: "Chats" })
```

Does anyone know how this can be done ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to mention the Chat Screen in the Same Hierarchy, I mean user details. You have to create separate navigator for every tabs.

```
const Tabs = createBottomTabNavigator({
    Home: Home,
    Profile: Profile,
    Chats: Chats
})

const UserDetailsNavigator = createStackNavigator({
   
    UserDetails: UserDetails,
    Chats: Chats

})
const ParentStack = createStackNavigator({
    Tabs: Tabs,
    UserDetailsNavigator: UserDetailsNavigator
})
```

That will work.